# Using extra() with foreign key on django model fails with DB error

Tags: sql, database, django, django-models

I'm trying to use django's extra() method to add a foreign key field to a queryset but i get DB errors. I am wondering what I'm doing wrong. Here's my setup:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rel = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

I am trying to use extra() to add a field from the related model so i can annotate() with it.
Here's what I am trying to do:

```
ModelB.objects.all().extra(select={'date' : 'date(rel.created)'}).values('date').annotate(...)
```

This gives me a DB error, saying that column "rel" does not exist.

I'm using PostgreSQL.
Could anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When using [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) you're explicitly writing SQL code. On the backend, `rel` is actually saved as `rel_id` and each row is a pk of a ModelA--which is why you're getting *column "rel" does not exist*.

You would need to rewrite your `extra(select={})` in proper sql:

```
ModelB.objects.all().extra(
    select={'date': '''SELECT created
                       FROM appname_modela
                       WHERE appname_modela.id = appname_modelb.rel_id'''})
```

However, as @Daniel Roseman said, your problem really doesn't need to use `extra()` at all, and I would strongly advise against it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't exist: the other table is called `model_a`.

But there's no reason to use `extra` here. You can get that column via the `values` call:

```
ModelB.objects.all().values('rel__created')...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although you are correct that I do not need extra() to get the information, i  was trying to use it to format the datetime field into a date only (using the date() function of the database) in order for me to perform annotate(). If i don't use that, each value i get in your queryset is slightly different in timestamp and therefore the count method in annotate() doesn't give me the result i want